# DataGridView.AutoResizeColumns is ignoring column header height

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which columns I want resized to the biggest cell from all that column's items, including the header. I have this:

```
dataGridViewMain.ColumnHeadersHeight = 60;
dataGridViewMain.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
```

Why does that code result in a few columns looking like this:

[image]

There is clearly more space reserved than necessary and I checked all the rows. None contain more than 3 characters. This behavior also happens on various columns. It looks like `AutoResizeColumns` calculates the space required without taking into account that the column header has a size of 60 and can accommodate various rows of text.

Comment: is it repeating column?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but no, this column is not repeated anywhere.

Answer (score 10):

Your grid header is re-sizing to the header text.
There is a property in `dataGridViewMain` you need to adjust.

Set as follows;

```
dataGridViewMain.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
```

Also this can be set via Property Window;

[image: Resize]

Comment: You interpreted my question wrong. I want it to be resized. My question is: Why is it re-sizing but leaving so much empty space to the right of the words. I want it to correctly resize to the biggest cell, including the header. It's clearly not doing that.

Comment: That last doesn't fit for one row. So it will break it to two lines like it. Try changing the modes and see whether it for your requirement

Comment: The text fits for all rows. There is no row with more than 3 characters, the header is the biggest cell, and this happens on various columns, not just the one I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try it  :)

```
this.dataGridViewMain.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
this.dataGridViewMain.ColumnHeadersHeight = 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;

you can change it in the Designer of your Form to see the changes during the building process of the form.

This works well for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing;
this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40;
this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)). Also, please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.